# Firebase storage upload fails because file type (error with jpg)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this code that convert a file to blob then send it to firebase for upload

```
    const response = await fetch(result.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(myref, blob);
```

When it's a `png` image everything works fine, if it's a picture taken with camera the ImagePicker from react native returns a `jpg` file and it crash my app without any console log error

How do I specify `png` as format for the uploaded images or how to avoid that issue?

Works ok

```
{
"assetId": null, "cancelled": false, 
"fileName": null, "fileSize": 143413, "height": 1334, 
"type": "image", 
"uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/.../Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/ImagePicker/720BB525-00DB-41D3-9DA1-A363071822BD.png", 
"width": 750
}
```

This crash the app for no apparent reason

```
{
"assetId": null, "cancelled": false, 
"fileName": null, "fileSize": 5099283, "height": 4032, 
"type": "image", 
"uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/E4F4E396-96C5-4FCF-906C-3413922215F5/Library/Caches/.../ImagePicker/7D408F07-ACB7-44A1-921D-E53835B8C55C.jpg", 
"width": 3024
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use base64 instead

```
const getBlob = async (uri) => {
    const res = await fetch(uri);
    return res.blob();
};
const blob = await getBlob(result.uri);
this.handleUpload(blob);
```